# Zend Application error if an unserialized object saved in $_SESSION since PHP 5.4

Tags: php, serialization, php-5.4, php-5.2, application-error

My Project is a mixed project (Non-Zend & Zend)
If i set  in a Non-Zend environment something like

```
$myObject = new MyObject();
$_SESSION['foo'] = $myObject;
```

and calling later a zend controller (http://mydomain.foo/zendControllerName) i get

"An error occurred
Application error"

It works only with serialized Objects in PHP 5.4
In PHP 5.2 it worked perfectly without serializing.

Answer (score 0):

The Solution.
[Why does my PHP with Zend Framework go crazy about "session started" since update to 5.4 (after a session exists on filesystem)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265245/why-does-my-php-with-zend-framework-go-crazy-about-session-started-since-updat)

You can set it in application.ini:

```
resources.session.throw_startup_exceptions = false
```